# How to justify that the sequence $n^n\bmod 5$ is periodic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm asked in an exercise to give the possible reminders of $n^{n} \bmod 5$ in a congruency that is a good fit for n.

After doing so calculations I note that there seems to be a cycle of reminders each $20$ numbers.

This is also supported by the fact that the reminder is related with $r5(n)$ but also with $r4(n)$ (the way I calculate the reminder, for $n$ that are coprime with $5$, is $r5( r5(n)^{r4(n)} )$ where $rX$ is the remainder modulo X).

I'm confident that the answer is related with the cycle of reminders from $n = 0$ to $n = 20$. All the reminders will repeat for $n \geq 20$. But I'm not sure what would be a good justification of this. I guess the fact that $4 | 20$ and $5 | 20$, it's the least common multiple, has something to do with this.

Comment: You can use [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to compute the remainder of $(n+20)^{n+20}=n^{n+20}+\text{ a multiple of }5$. And then the remainder of $n^{n+20}=n^n(n^5)^4$. Using Fermat's little theorem conclude that the remainder of $(n^5)^4$ is $1$ if $n$ is not divisible by $5$ or $0$ when it is. In both cases $(n+20)^{n+20}$ ends up with the same remainder as $n^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about $20$ being the least common multiple of $4$ and $5$ being relevant. Using Fermat's Little Theorem, we have
$$a^5 \equiv a \ \mathbf{mod} \ 5,$$
for all $a$. So, if $n > 1$, we have
\begin{align*}
(n + 20)^{n + 20} &\equiv (n + 20)^{n-1} (n + 20)^{21} \\
&\equiv (n + 20)^{n-1} (n + 20) \\
&\equiv (n + 20)^n \\
&\equiv n^n.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, if $n = 1$, then
$$21^{21} \equiv 1^{21} \equiv 1.$$
In any case, we get what we want.

Comment: "On the other hand, if $n=1$, then ..." What do you mean by this? I mean, what is this supposed to add to the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your expression $r5(n)^{r4(n)}$ only depends on $n\bmod 5$ and $n\bmod 4$.  The pair of values of these repeat every $20$ as shown in the Chinese Remainder Theorem.